# Pass case when variable to another case

Tags: sql-server

I have a query as following, would like to tidy it up by passing isMatchingNameEmail into the second case when,

my ultimate goal is find matching referenceID by the following logic:

return database's referenceID
if there is anything matching on firstname + emailaddress, if not then try to find it matching on firstname and mobile number, if not return blank

just want to see if theres a better way to do it.
thanks guys!

```
    select r.*,
    L.U3L_ReferenceID ReferenceID,
    case when L.U3L_ReferenceID is null then
        (select L.U3L_ReferenceID from [u3_data].[data].[ListData_e0a27] [L]
        where r.given_name = L.firstname and r.email = L.emailaddress)
        end isMatchingNameEmail,
    -- when record is not found and isMatchingNameEmail is null
    case when L.U3L_ReferenceID is null
        and (select top 1 L.U3L_ReferenceID from [u3_data].[data].[ListData_e0a27] [L]
        where r.given_name = L.firstname and r.email = L.emailaddress) is null
        then
        (select L.U3L_ReferenceID from [u3_data].[data].[ListData_e0a27] [L]
        where 
        r.given_name = L.firstname and
            (replace(
            replace( 
            replace(
            replace(r.mobilephone
                    ,' ','')
                    ,'(','')
                    ,')','')
                    ,'+','') = L.mobilenumber or
            replace(
            replace( 
            replace(
            replace(r.mobilephone
                    ,' ','')
                    ,'(','')
                    ,')','')
                    ,'+','') = stuff(L.mobilenumber,1,2,'0') or
            replace(
            replace( 
            replace(
            replace(r.mobilephone
                    ,' ','')
                    ,'(','')
                    ,')','')
                    ,'+','') = L.mobilenumber))
        end isMatchingNameMobile
    from @Records r
    left Join [u3_data].[data].[ListData_e0a27] [L] with(nolock) on
    [r].Id = [L].userid
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's generally not possible to reference a column alias elsewhere in the `select`. Perhaps try a different join approach?

Comment: use `CTE` or `DERIVED TABLE` or `APPLY`

Comment: I think you are making things complex. Can you please provide some sample data and your expected output please? This will help.

Comment: using the same alias for multiple tables to me makes this even more confusing.  Note: you could do another join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a CTE

```
; with 
cte1 as
(
    select col1, col2, <query expression> as col3 from yourtable
),
cte2 as
(
    select col1, col2, col3, col3 * 4 as col4 from cte1
)
select col1, col2, col3, col4 
from   cte2
```

using derived table

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from
(
     select col1, col2, col3, col3 * 4 as col4
     from
     (
         select col1, col3, <query expression> as col3 from yourtable
     ) as d
) as d
```

using apply operator

```
select t.col1, t.col2, a3.col3, a4.col4
from   yourtable t
       cross apply
       (
            select <query expression> as col3
       ) a1
       cross apply
       (
            select col3 * 4 as col4
       ) a
```